# Overfitting with Non Negative Least Squares

Tags: overfitting, fitting, linear-algebra

I'm trying to reconstruct a function, $A(x)$ from the results of some detectors. Essentially, I have a set of $n$ points which are

$ V_{i} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(x) e^{-(x - v_{i})^{2}} dx $

Effectively this means I have a set of functions detecting about a small window, where $V_{i}$ gives me the integral of that multiplied with the underlying function. My plan is to try to approximately recover the underlying function using an NNLS method.

To do this, I'm saying that $\underline{V}$ is a vector of length $n$ containing my values $V_{i}$. I then have a vector of length $t$, $\underline{A}$, which is the unknown I want to obtain (over some $x$, made up of $t$ points). I can construct a matrix, $\underline{\underline{M}}$, which is $n \times t$ where the rows are the exponentials evaluated over the same $x$. Then

$\underline{V} = \underline{\underline{M}} \times \underline{A}$

and so

$\underline{A} = \underline{\underline{M}}^{-1} \underline{V}$

which I can solve using NNLS. My question is firstly, is this approach reasonable? And secondly, how large can I make $t$. I'd have thought that seeing as this is essentially least squares fitting, the number of parameters I could fit would be $t \leq n$ - but I'm not sure?

Thank you

Comment: This problem is known as *deconvolution.*

Comment: I did think about deconvolution, but my detectors aren't linearly spaced - they might be at [1,2,3, 6, 7, 13, 15], but the actual underlying function is across this whole range. Is there a way to deconvolve a sparse space like this? Thank you

Comment: It's still a deconvolution!  The issue is how to compute it.  The nature of your data is important and worth mentioning in the question itself.